# how can I fix Simu5G error when it is building?

Tags: omnet++, inet, simulte

I have some error when I try to import Simu5G in Omnet++
here is my error.

```
   **** Build of configuration gcc-debug for project simu5G ****`enter code here`
  Error: cannot resolve import 'inet.common.INETDefs'

  Error: cannot resolve import 'inet.common.packet.chunk.Chunk'

  Error: cannot resolve import 'inet.common.geometry.Geometry'
  Error: 'MultihopD2DPacket': unknown base class 'inet::FieldsChunk'
  Error: unknown type 'inet::Coord' for field 'srcCoord' in 'MultihopD2DPacket'
  Error: Unknown field 'chunkLength' (not found in any super class)
  Error: cannot resolve import 'inet.common.INETDefs'
  Error: cannot resolve import 'inet.common.packet.chunk.Chunk'
  Error: 'AlertPacket': unknown base class 'inet::FieldsChunk'
  [Makefile:339: apps/cbr/CbrPacket_m.h] Error 1
  *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not have (an installed) INET project in your workspace, or the INET project is not open or it is not set as a project dependency in Simu5G's project properties dialog.

Comment: Thank you, but I've installed Inet (it has warning mark), and also I think it's open. Could you please tell me how to set that as a project dependency in Simu5G? I did everything in the installation guide step by step.  I tried different versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the similar issue in SimuLTE. This is due to an invalid project reference setting. To fix it:
Right Click the projet - Property - Project Reference, then select the inet you installed.

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. It seems this probelm happens when I install INET manually and Simu5G is looking for the internal inet project. Under 'Project Reference', I can see two options for inet.